# Google Apiclient, Google Drive, after uploaded file empty

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I upload file some formats and in google drive have file with empty body. Why not understand

I install google api client

```
        "name": "google/apiclient",
        "version": "1.1.7",
```

and try upload file in google dics
I get access token help with HWIO bundle, add scope

```
scope:               
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
```

and get accesToken like this

```
{"access_token":"TOKEN", "refresh_token":"TOKEN", "token_type":"Bearer",
 "expires_in":3600, "id_token":"TOKEN", "created":1320790426}
```

beign I try upload exist file (doc, pdf, img)

```
    $client = $this->get('artel.google.api.client');

    /** @var CodeUserReference[] $accessToken */
    $accessToken = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:CodeUserReference')
        ->getReferenceAccessClient($user);
    if ($accessToken) {
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken[0]->getAccessTokenClient());
    } else {
        $view = $this->view(['No accessToken was found for this user id'], 400);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client->getGoogleClient());
    $file = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName($request->request->get('title')
        ? $request->request->get('title')
        : $request->files->get('file')->getClientOriginalName()
    );
    $file->setDescription($request->request->get('description'));
    $file->setMimeType($request->request->get('mimeType')
        ? $request->request->get('mimeType')
        : $request->files->get('file')->getClientMimeType()
    );

    // Set the parent folder.Google_Service_Drive_ParentReferen, this class not find in google/apiclient, version": "1.1.7", I don\'t know why..(
    if ($request->request->get('parentId') != null) {
        $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReferen();
        $parent->setId($request->request->get('parentId'));
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
    }

    try {
        $data = $request->files->get('file');

        $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => $request->request->get('mimeType')
                ? $request->request->get('mimeType')
                : $request->files->get('file')->getClientMimeType(),
            'uploadType' => 'media'
        ));

        // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
        // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();
        return View::create()
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setData([$createdFile]);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $view = $this->view((array) $e->getMessage(), 400);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```

have response

```
  {
"internal_gapi_mappings": [],
"model_data": [],
"processed": [],
"collection_key": "spaces",
"capabilities_type": "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities",
"capabilities_data_type": "",
"content_hints_type": "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints",
"content_hints_data_type": "",
"id": "0B2_i_Tc5Vr8UWV9Jc2psQkhqS3M",
"image_media_metadata_type": "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata",
"image_media_metadata_data_type": "",
"kind": "drive#file",
"last_modifying_user_type": "Google_Service_Drive_User",
"last_modifying_user_data_type": "",
"mime_type": "application/msword",
"name": "Resume — Symfony Backend Developer, PHP, Shuba Ivan.doc",
"owners_type": "Google_Service_Drive_User",
"owners_data_type": "array",
"permissions_type": "Google_Service_Drive_Permission",
"permissions_data_type": "array",
"sharing_user_type": "Google_Service_Drive_User",
"sharing_user_data_type": "",
"video_media_metadata_type": "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata",
"video_media_metadata_data_type": ""
```

}

all I have in file this:

```
/tmp/phpaPpHBp
```

I use this [doc v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#try-it) because in "name": "google/apiclient", "version": "1.1.7" no find function "insert",

So, mime_type correct but inside emty, only like this - /tmp/phpaPpHBp
I try some uploadType - media, multipart, resumable but stil empty
When try pdf mime_type =  application/pdf but still emty
What I\'am doing wrong and why I have emty file in google drive?

anybody, who knows, help

Answer (score 0):

add file_get_content and work fine :

```
    if ($request->request->get('parentId') !== null) {
        $parent = new \Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
        $parent->setId($request->request->get('parentId'));
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
    }

    $insertArray = [
        'mimeType' => isset($fileUpload) ? $fileUpload->getClientMimeType() :  $request->request->get('mimeType')
    ];

    if (isset($fileUpload)) {
        $insertArray ['uploadType'] = 'media';
        $insertArray ['data'] = file_get_contents($fileUpload);
    }

    try {
        $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, $insertArray);

        return View::create()
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setData([$createdFile]);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $view = $this->view((array) self::ERROR_OCCURRED . $e->getMessage(), 400);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```